# Make Existing Package Version in Virtual Environment Stick

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, virtualenv, dependency-management

I have a utility called `backup-tool` (fictional). This has a direct dependency
on a third-party library called `security-utils` (fictional, again). And this
dependency has a dependency on `cryptography` (a real dependency). So,
`backup-tool` has a transitive dependency on `cryptography`. No particular
versions are demanded neither from `backup-tool` nor from `security-utils`.

Now I have two servers: one running Linux, and one running FreeBSD. I create a
virtual environment on Linux and run `pip install backup-tool` under it.
Everything works fine.

On FreeBSD, `cryptography` with the version 2.9.2 can be installed without any
issues. Other versions, however, cause a build failure. (Workarounds could be
found, for sure, but this is not the point.)

Now I setup a virtual environment and pre-install the right version using `pip install cryptography==2.9.2`. Later on—this is all setup in an automated
pipeline, and I cannot join those two steps—my tool is installed using `pip install backup-tool`. The transient dependency to `cryptography` is resolved as
a version 3.x, which doesn't work.

However, if I run `pip install backup-tool cryptography==2.9.2` in a single
step, everything works. This means that `backup-tool` is compatible to
`cryptography` in the version 2.9.2.

My question: **Is it possible to hint to pip within the virtual environment that
no other version of `cryptography` should be installed, if it is already
there?** The dependency tree could as well be resolved to match the version
already installed, but the latest version is picked instead.

I could further specify the (transient) dependency `cryptography==2.9.2` in the
`requirements.txt` or `setup.py` of `backup-tool`. But since this is rather an
environment than a software constraint, it would be useless restriction for most
setups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [constraints file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files) to limit the range of package versions pip should try when the package is being installed. The syntax is that of a requirements file.

e.g. `constraints.txt`:

```
cryptography==2.9.2
```

For the pip to always read this constraints file you can set environment variable:

```sh
export PIP_CONSTRAINT=constraints.txt
```

Or, under virtual environment, create config at `$VIRTUAL_ENV/pip.conf`:

```
[install]
constraint = constraints.txt
```

(paths are relative to your app root)